# What is the story of the scene carved on wood?

Tags: identification-request

Can someone enlighten me on the scene carved in wood here? Seems very interesting but I'm quite new to Hinduism.

[image]

Comment: Where did you see this? @vDyke

Comment: Hello Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. Are you sure it is about Hinduism? Where did you find this image? Have you tried reverse image search? Adding following details will help us know what is happening in the scene. Lack of details with just an image which is unsure if it is Hinduism related makes it close as unclear what you are asking.